# python rewrite sqlite3 library at compile time

Tags: python, dll, sqlite, compilation

I'm currently facing this issue with sqlite3 on python:
*Exception Value: too many SQL variables*.
To solve it, I would like to change the value of *SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER*, which defaults to 999 and increase it to 9999.

With what I have seen, this is only possible by changing source files and re-compile sqlite3 myself. To do it, I have followed the sqlite3 documentation, took the amalgamated source code files, changed the value in sqlite3.c and generated a proper DLL with MSVC.

My question is what do I need to do with this DLL ? Do I need to change the one that I have from sqlite3 first compilation in Python2.7/DLLs?

This is what I did, but I now have this issue:
not a valid win32 application despite the fact that I compiled it in x64 and my python is also in x64. Is it related with the .pyd file which is also present in python2.7/DLLs ? I am now a bit confused on the procedure I should follow.

Comment: Nobody has an idea on how to solve this please?